# Homing Fireball - Seiken Densetsu 3 style

Tags: architecture, algorithm

I'd like to reproduce the fireball spell of Seiken Densetsu 3.
The Fireballs  don't follow the target directly, but encircle it more or less until they hit the target.

I have no idea how to reproduce this encircling.
I tried using the Forward Vector of my Fireball and adding it to the velocity. At the same time, the Rotation is slowly interpolated.

But no matter how I tweak the values, my fireballs mostly miss the target due to too slow rotation or the fireballs go straight to the target due to too fast rotation.

Does someone have a formula/ can point me into the right direction?
Here's a video on how the Fireballs in SD3 work:
https://youtu.be/PxtHGny88DM

Note how sometimes a fireball misses and encircles the target before it hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks similar to gravitational orbit.

[image]

Basically, you make the fireball accelerate toward the target, and give it an initial speed in a direction perpendicular to the target.

Then you play around with the acceleration parameter and initial speed parameter until you get the effect you want. In your case, you probably want a higher value for acceleration.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Orbitting is exaclty what I want to avoid.

Comment: The fireballs in your video do orbit for a while before hitting the target. You can control when the orbit ends by adjusting the acceleration. Remember that even Earth is not in a perpetual orbit, and would eventually close in on the Sun.

Comment: The Fireball still orbits. the target.

I'm using the following formula:
`Vel := length(Target.Pos - Fireball.Pos)`
`Accel := Map Distance from [0,2000] to [1,0.1]` (A distance > 2000 returns 1, a distance near 0 returns 0.1)
`Vel := Vel*accel`

Comment: Thank you, I got a better solution now by adjusting the Speed with Distance, but also with time. The Longer the Fireball exists, the faster it will be together with the distance.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ccm2_cPK_fQ&feature